# Diff command in Bash Shell Scipt

Tags: bash

Can someone please explain the meaning of the below statement.

```
diff -u file1 -
```

From what i understand, diff commands shows the differences between two input files. However, in the above scenario, it takes only one input file.

Comment: my intuition, without verifying, is you can do a `cat another_file | diff -u file1 -`

Answer (score 2):

From [the man page for `diff`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html):

> If a FILE is '-', read standard input.

So the command `diff -u file1 -` reads `file1`, and reads everything from standard input (probably being piped from some other program), and compares the two.